# How should the implicit sum $C_{ijkl}u_{i,j}u_{k,l}$ be interpreted?

Tags: notation, tensor-calculus

$C$ is a 3x3x3x3 tensor. How should the expression $C_{ijkl}u_{i,j}u_{k,l}$ be interpreted? This is my guess:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 
\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{l=1}^3
C_{ijkl}u_{i,j}u_{k,l}
$$

Comment: That looks correct to me, even if without any context is not so easy to say.

Comment: Yes, applying [Einstein summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) the sums are implicitely assumed. More correctly, one of the two summed over indices should be an upper (contravariant) index and the other one a lower (covariant) index.

Comment: What would be the alternative?

Comment: More on Einstein notation: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Einstein+[notation]

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure since I'm not used to tensors nor Einstein notation.

Comment: @DavidZ The alternative is that if either $u$ or the searched result is something unconventional, no sums have to be applied.

Comment: You are dealing with elastic energy, aren't you? If yes Einstein's convention is supposed.