# Are derivative indices summed in indicial notation?

Tags: notation

A paper I'm reading uses indicial notation and the convention that $u_{j,k}$ means the derivative with respect to $x_k$. Which one of these interpretations are correct?

$$A_{ijk}u_{j,k} = \sum_{j}A_{ijk} \frac{\delta u_j}{\delta x_k}$$

$$A_{ijk}u_{j,k} = \sum_{j,k}A_{ijk} \frac{\delta u_j}{\delta x_k}$$

Comment: It's almost certainly the second one, but to be 100% sure, it would help if you could link to the paper or say a bit more about the context.  Also, are those supposed to be functional derivatives or partial derivatives?

Comment: Also, why aren't they using raised indices?

Comment: @joshphysics [Paper on Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23686942) and [direct link to PDF that might work](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3794076/pdf/nihms494056.pdf), eq. 5. They are partial derivatives.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Do you mean to distinguish between covariance and contravariance?

Comment: Is the index $k$ present on the other side of the equation? If not, it has to be summed over. Would not make sense otherwise.

Comment: @nephente Unless the resulting vector/matrix/tensor had a reduntant dimension that would be useful later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should the implicit sum $C_{ijkl}u_{i,j}u_{k,l}$ be interpreted?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96538/)

Comment: Anna, I'm voting to close as duplicate. I don't mean this as a slight on your question, I simply think it would be tidier if you asked this question as well as your other one (linked by @ChrisWhite) as one question alone: the answers are going to be simple confirmations of usage, since you do not seem to have a conceptual problem here. Also, please include the link you gave to JoshPhysics so that there is some background. Notation for tensors is wont to be a bit of a free-for-all and not consistent outside relativity and mathematics, so answering is hard without context.

Comment: @Anna: I posted a related question that does some of the math used in the paper you linked, in case you're interested: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97851/nonsensical-dispersion-relations-for-elastic-wave-propagation

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I was interested, thanks for notifying me!